# Show the non-existence of primitive

Tags: complex-analysis

Assume the function $f(z) = \frac{1}{z-1}$ $-$ $\frac{1}{z+1}$

(a) Prove that $f(z)$ does not have a primitive in $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{-1, 1\}$

(b) Prove that $f(z)$ has a primitive in $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{t+0\mathcal{i}\,| t \in [-1,1] \}$

Question: I do not quite understand this question; if we set $F(z) = \log(z-1) - \log(z+1)$, then $F'(z) = f(z)$, right? Any help to prove this?

Comment: What is your $F(0)$?

Comment: I see, not defined at z=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\log z$ is not even  a well-defined valued function, let alone analytic. So your argument fails.

Hints: consider the circle $|z+1|=1$. Show that the integral of of $f$ over this is not zero. Since the integral of a derivative over any closed path is necesarily $0$ it follows that $f$ cannot have a primitive  in $\mathbb C\setminus \{-1,1\}$.
For the second part verify the following: If $z \notin [-1,1]$ the $\frac {z-1} {z+1} \in  \mathbb C\setminus (-\infty,0]$. Let Log denote the principle branch of logarithm. This function  is analytic in $\mathbb C\setminus (-\infty,0]$ and the derivative of $Log (\frac {z-1} {z+1})$ is $f$.

Comment: "Multivalued functions" are nonsense (and its an old term we better dispense already). Simply state that there is no way to define $\log$ in the whole of $\mathbf{C}$ making it analytic.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the first part, for the second part, how can we show the derivative of Log(z-1/z+1) is f?

Comment: @MikeQ The derivative of $Log z$ is \frac 1 z$. Apply Chain rule to differentiate $\Log(\frac {z-1} {z+1})$.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get a primitive vanishing at a point $z_0$, you  should calculate the integral on the line from $z_0$ to $z$  of this function, and since your function is holomorphic this integral does not depend on your path thanks to Cauchy theorem, in particular the integral from $z_0$ to $z_0$ is zero (if you consider a closer path a circle cdntred on $z_0$ for example).
So if you want to calculate the integral :
$$
\int_{\mathcal{C}(1,1)} \frac{dz}{z-1}
$$
Using the change of variable $z=e^{it}+1$
$$
\int_{\mathcal{C}(1,1)} \frac{dz}{z-1}=\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{ie^{it}}{e^{it}}dt=2i\pi\neq 0
$$
So the primitive can't be well defined in such case. 
But if instead of that we take a line from the plan  such that we cannot make a circle around the point 1, the problem with the primitive is resulved.